# N tasks assigned uniformly and independently at random to n computers. Calculate the variance of the number of computers that receive 0 tasks

Tags: probability

**$n$ tasks are assigned uniformly and independently at random to $n$ computers. Calculate the variance of the number of computers that receive 0 tasks**

> Let $c_1,...,c_n$ be the computers.
>
> Let $C_i$ = 1 if computer $c_i$ receives no task, 0 otherwise.
>
> $C=\Sigma C_i$
>
> $\mathbb{P}(C_i=1) = (\frac{n-1}{n})^n$
>
> $\mathbb{E}(C)=n(\frac{n-1}{n})^n$

So now I want to find $Var(C)$.

> $Var(C)=\sum\limits_{i=1}{n}[ \mathbb{P}(C_i=1) - \mathbb{P}(C_i=1)^2]+ \sum\limits_{i\not=j}[ \mathbb{P}[C_i=1 \ \text{and} \ C_j=1] -p_ip_j] $
>
> $=\sum\limits_{i=1}{n}[(\frac{n-1}{n})^n-(\frac{n-1}{n})^{2n}]+
>  \sum\limits_{i\not=j}[(\frac{n-1}{n})^n(\frac{n-2}{n})^{n} -
>  (\frac{n-1}{n})^{2n}] $

I think I am a bit lost

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You are interested in $E(C^2) - \big(E(C)\big)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The $C_i$ have identical distribution, but are probably not independent. So the variance is not the sum of variances.

Use: $$\text{Var}C=\mathbb EC^2-\left(\mathbb EC\right)^2$$
and applying symmetry:
$$\mathbb EC^2=\mathbb E(\sum_{i=1}^nC_i)^2=\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nC_iC_j=n\mathbb EC_1^2+n(n-1)\mathbb EC_1C_2=n\mathbb EC_1+n(n-1)\mathbb EC_1C_2$$
The last equality because $C_1^2=C_1$